# Protractor + Jenkins , element not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, jenkins

On my local, I start e2e tests in Protractor and this is good.
I have problem when I want start tests on Jenkins job.

- I pull tests from repo
- run command `npm install`
- run command `node_modules\.bin\ng e2e --webdriver-update`

My tests start execution and I have problem:

```
` W/element - more than one element found for locator by.buttonText("Create") - the first result will be used
[31mÃ— Check Item in RAID Type drop-down-menu[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mFailed: element not interactable
    (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)[39m
    (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)
      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newJob\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newJob\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
      at doSend.then.response (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newJob\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)`
```

Comment: As per error details, it is specific to an element.Does it mean browser launches successfully ?

Comment: Also before this step ,does automation interacts with any other element successfully? If so, then it's simply a case of element not interactable.Nothing specific to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming browser launches successfully and test is able to interact with any other element successfully before the element having issues.

Use explicit wait for the desired element as below:

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('NON-EXISTING-ELEMENT')), 3000, 'error message')
```

As it seems that element is not ready yet for interaction.Also if you share the code & relevant html snippet as well , then all might  be able to suggest better solutions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. All my code work work fine in my local machine. And when I start my code on Jenkins job, I have problem. Element  not interactable.

Comment: What are the specifics? Where is your code? Relevant html source? Jenkins job details?It is hard for anybody else to help you without further information.

Answer (score 0):

this is my Protractor code.

```
it('Creating default configuration ', () => {
        _home.getPowerConfiguration().click();

        _descriptionModel.buttonStartCreate().click();
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            _wizard.buttonNext().click();
        }
        _descriptionModel.buttonCreate().click();
        expect(_configuration.geImage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true).then(function (result) {
            expect(_configurationView.getNebu().count()).toBe(2);
            expect(_configurationView.getimage().count()).toBe(2);
            expect(_configurationView.getImage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

This is work on my local machine, but does not on Jenkins.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.